# OP has edited his question and completely changed it

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, ethics

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22904112/1864610) was asked today. The OP posted a lengthy assignment and asked for clarification on his course. I indicated that I thought this was off topic and voted to close. Later, I found the OP has edited the question and completely changed the content. Now the question is perhaps on-topic if rather poor.

Should I roll back the edits and comment the question suggesting the OP to create a new question? Or should I just leave it alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not actually a totally new question, just a refined version of their older question. As a result, it looks to me like the OP's edits actually satisfy exactly what putting questions on hold (in this case, probably as "unclear what you're asking") intends. They improved their post to better meet the criteria of a Stack Overflow question.

While I agree with you, it is still a poor question, it is an improvement from their previous revision in the sense that it is no longer unclear what they are asking. However, I believe this *other* close reason still applies:

> This question appears to be off-topic because **it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem**...

I think the best decision for you is to leave the question be - you've already VTCd, so the most you can do is retract that.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was going to say "I guess I'll just leave it be.", but it's been closed now anyway.